# Play 2.3.3 heroku deployment error

Tags: heroku, playframework-2.3

i'm trying to deploy a play! framework 2.3.3 application to heroku this is the response from deployment window

```
Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 814, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (786/786), done.
Writing objects: 100% (814/814), 5.80 MiB | 10.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 814 (delta 316), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Play 2.x - Java app detected
-----> Installing OpenJDK 1.8...done
-----> Downloading SBT...done
-----> Priming Ivy cache (Scala-2.11, Play-2.3)... done
-----> Running: sbt update
   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512M; suppo
rt was removed in 8.0
   [info] Loading project definition from /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/pro
ject
   [error] /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/project/Build.scala:3: object Proj
ect is not a member of package play
   [error] import play.Project._
   [error]             ^
   [error] /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/project/Build.scala:14: not found:
value filters
   [error]    filters,
   [error]    ^
   [error] /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/project/Build.scala:20: not found:
value javaCore
   [error]       javaCore,
   [error]       ^
   [error] /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/project/Build.scala:21: not found:
value javaJdbc
   [error]       javaJdbc,
   [error]       ^
   [error] /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/project/Build.scala:22: not found:
value javaEbean
   [error]       javaEbean,
   [error]       ^
   [error] /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/project/Build.scala:23: not found:
value cache
   [error]       cache
   [error]       ^
   [error] /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/project/Build.scala:28: object Pro
ject is not a member of package play
   [error]     val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies)
.settings(
   [error]                     ^
   [error] 7 errors found
   [error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
   Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?  !     Fail
ed to run sbt task: update

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Play 2.x - Java app

To git@heroku.com:obscure-scrubland-1026.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:obscure-scrubland-1026.git'
```

this is a what build.sbt looks like

```
import play.PlayJava

name := "schoolapp"

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

val appDependencies = Seq(
  "be.objectify"  %% "deadbolt-java"     % "2.3.0-RC1",
  // Comment the next line for local development of the Play Authentication core:
  "com.feth"      %% "play-authenticate" % "0.6.5-SNAPSHOT",
  "postgresql"    %  "postgresql"        % "9.1-901-1.jdbc4",
  javaCore,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean
)

resolvers ++= Seq(
"Apache" at "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/",
"jBCrypt Repository" at "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/",
"play-easymail (release)" at "http://joscha.github.io/play-easymail/repo/releases/",
"play-easymail (snapshot)" at "http://joscha.github.io/play-easymail/repo/snapshots/",
Resolver.url("Objectify Play Repository", url("http://schaloner.github.io/releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),
"play-authenticate (release)" at "http://joscha.github.io/play-authenticate/repo/releases/",
"play-authenticate (snapshot)" at "http://joscha.github.io/play-authenticate/repo/snapshots/"
)

//  Uncomment the next line for local development of the Play Authenticate core:
//lazy val playAuthenticate = project.in(file("modules/play-authenticate")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

 lazy val root = project.in(file("."))
 .enablePlugins(PlayJava)
 .settings(
 libraryDependencies ++= appDependencies
 )
 //  Uncomment the next lines for local development of the Play Authenticate core:
 //.dependsOn(playAuthenticate)
 //.aggregate(playAuthenticate)
```

i'm using the play authenticate module. what could be the problem?

Comment: The problem appears to be in your `project/Build.scala`. can you share that file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove `import play.Project._` and add `import play.PlayImport._` in your `project/Build.scala` file.